# Bamboo variable doesn't accept spaces?

Tags: powershell, arguments, command-line-arguments, bamboo

I have a PowerShell script that I trigger from Bamboo, the script basically accepts 3 string parameters:

```
Param([string]$language, [string]$architecture ="x64", [string]$version)

$x64Path = "some path..."
$x86Path = "some path.."
$arguments = $language,$architecture,$version

If($architecture -eq "x64") {
    Write-Host "Executing:" $x64Path" at x64 using" $language "and" $version
   # & $x64Path $arguments
} 
Else {
   Write-Host "Executing:" $x86Path "at x86 using" $language "and" $version
  # & $x86Path $arguments
}
```

if I run the PowerShell script from the ISE, for example:

```
.\MyScript.ps1 "JPN" "x64" "AB 6.0 R"
```

I will correctly get this output:

```
Executing: some path... at x64 using JPN and AB 6.0 R
```

I have created a plan in Bamboo with the following:

## Variables

[image]

## Task

[image]

I have tried adding the variables (argument) as:

```
"${bamboo.Language}" "${bamboo.Architecture}" ${bamboo.Version}
```

and aso as:

```
"${bamboo.Language}" "${bamboo.Architecture}" "${bamboo.Version}"
```

But I always get the same output:

```
Executing: some path... at x64 using JPN and AB
```

Notice that the last variable is cut out (I don't get the full **AB 6.0 R**)

Is this a bug in Bamboo, or something I'm doing wrong? or is there a workaround it?

PS. To achieve this run in Bamboo (by giving the variable values), I'm running the plan as follows:
[image]

Comment: Does `"'${bamboo.Version}'"` make a difference (notice nested quotes)

Comment: That solved it! I can't believe it was that simple! If you want to write the answer in the big Answer box I'll mark yours as the one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the quotes get stripped after variable replacement in bamboo (ie. before the arguments are passed to powershell).

Add an inner set of single-quotes to the argument that has spaces:

```
"${bamboo.Language}" "${bamboo.Architecture}" "'${bamboo.Version}'"
```